# Mysql treating varchar as int bug?

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, where-clause

I just ran this query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycol='text' WHERE mycol=0;
```

The point being that the column `mycol` is a *varchar*, yet i treated is as an *int* as well.
To my surprise, the where clause evaluated to true on ALL rows of the table, empty or not.

So, why does a nonempty string compare equal to an integer zero?

Comment: It's not a bug. PHP does the same. When comparing string to int, it tries to parse that string into int, in case of no success, it threats it as 0.

Comment: Not only is it not a bug, it's kind of handy at times.

Comment: Thank you all, i dont know why but i thought the int gets casted to a (null) string.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very well documented behavior in MySQL.

When a string is encountered in a context that calls for a number, MySQL converts the string to a number, starting with digits at the beginning of the string.  It stops when there are no digits.  So, a string with no digits becomes 0.

If you want a proper comparison, use single quotes:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycol='text' WHERE mycol = '0';
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html) is the exact quote:

> To cast a string to a numeric value in numeric context, you normally
>   do not have to do anything other than to use the string value as
>   though it were a number:
>
> mysql> SELECT 1+'1';
>          -> 2