# MySQL treats string as integer

Tags: php, mysql

I have huge problem with my application. Before I start I red these subjects [Mysql treating varchar as int bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843329/mysql-treating-varchar-as-int-bug), and [mysql autocasting string to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762038/mysql-autocasting-string-to-integer).

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `srv_table` (
  `srv_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `srv_code` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`srv_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`srv_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When i try to select rows by primary key and send mixed string it returns me results. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM srv_table WHERE srv_id='2sadf'
```

will return same result as:

```
SELECT * FROM srv_table WHERE srv_id=2
```

I know that this is documented in MySQL, but I couldn't find how i can avoid that. Is there a setting or something else I could do **without change my code and queries**?

Regards.

**UPDATE:**
For these guys that don't beleive that it returns same result when id value is wrapped by single quotes:

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e9289/1)

**UPDATE 2:**

It seems this is not an issue in PostgreSQL:
[PgSQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/352fa0/2)

Comment: your srv_id is integer, and it actually ignores characters...whats the problem actually??

Comment: If you want to make sure that only integer values are used to query your data – then you should ensure that in your application logic, before the value gets passed to the database.

Comment: The problem is that i don't want such a behavior. Is there a way to avoid it, or i have to change my application to filter the input?

Comment: you should in application filter your string, check if its integer, or strip string characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect to happen?  You have an integer column and you are comparing it to a string.  That is a bad idea.  MySQL converts both to integers, using silent conversion (i.e., it converts the leading digits).

If you really want to do this, then use explicit conversion:

```
SELECT *
FROM srv_table 
WHERE cast(srv_id as varchar) = '2sadf';
```

But it seems like a bad idea.  Compare integer fields to integers, not strings.

Comment: I need to compare integers, not strings. For me it is not logical to treat strings as integer.

Comment: @bksi . . . Whether you think it is logical or not, the database has to do a conversion to compare a string and an integer, if that is how you write the SQL statement.  Others probably think that converting both to strings is not logical.  The solution is to not have implicit conversions in the SQL code.

Comment: Is there a setting that makes SQL to throw an error when tries to compare different data types?

Comment: @bksi . . . I am not aware of one.  I don't even think that sql mode "ANSI" will eliminate the errors on silent conversion.

Comment: @bksi this is the best answer above the others... you should be controlling the conversions/casting yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can use LIKE but the best thing is to ensure that an integer value is passed from your data. Try the code below:

```
SELECT * FROM srv_table WHERE srv_id LIKE '2'
```

Comment: Actually this query works. But i need (if possible) to set something in mysql config to disable the silent conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using 'BINARY' in your SQL query ?

```
SELECT * FROM srv_table WHERE BINARY srv_id='2sadf'
```

query above will return empty row since the 'srv_id' column is integer.

Comment: Actualy not, it returns same result. I tried both quotes and single quotes

Comment: it should return empty rows since that query will exactly find '2sadf' on your srv_id column which should not exists since srv_id coulmn type is INT.

Comment: Check my updated question. There is sql fiddle, you can see for yourself ;)

Comment: i try using BINARY on your SQLFiddle, and it returns zero rows.

Comment: And how i will use auto_increment on BINARY? Note that i need minimum php code intervention :)

Comment: i think i didn't get what do you want to do..i didn't see what BINARY has to do with auto_increment since i use it in your query syntax, not create table syntax.

if you want to get the exact records, then i suggest you used BINARY on your SQL select syntax.

Comment: All i need is (if it possible) to dissable somehow this silent conversion and MySQL to throw error, or return me empty row.

Comment: if you try my answer in your SQL fiddle, it should return empty row.

Comment: True, but as i said if it possible to change MySQL behavior instead. I thank you for your suggestions and i will give you +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
SELECT * FROM `srv_table` WHERE  binary(`srv_id`) = '3ххххх';
```

Hope it will help you.