# Laravel's Where clause returning wrong/unexpected results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 records:

```
= Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4789
all: [
  App\Models\ModelName {#4790
    id: 2,
    reference: "3f716d49-48e5-46be-bb91-33b35a042b9f",
    user_id: 5,
    deliverer_id: null,
    amount: "5000.00",
    amountCharged: "5000.00",
    fees_applied: "[]",
    payment_method: "{"wallet": "wallet"}",
    delivery_address: "Location",
    region: null,
    lat: "xxxx",
    long: "xxxx",
    status: "pending",
    paymentstatus: "unpaid",
    delivered_at: null,
    created_at: "2023-03-12 13:33:20",
    updated_at: "2023-03-12 13:33:20",
    deleted_at: null,
  },
  App\Models\ModelName {#4791
    id: 9,
    reference: "2c101e9b-9bb8-4efe-9e12-3c94a19d658d",
    user_id: 2,
    deliverer_id: 6,
    amount: "5000.00",
    amountCharged: "5000.00",
    fees_applied: "[]",
    payment_method: "{"card": "cardDetails"}",
    delivery_address: "city",
    region: null,
    lat: "xxxxxxxxx",
    long: "xxxxxxxx",
    status: "accepted",
    paymentstatus: "paid",
    delivered_at: null,
    created_at: "2023-04-01 09:56:07",
    updated_at: "2023-04-02 00:01:34",
    deleted_at: null,
  },
],}
```

Running the following Tinker command gets the correct data:

```
App\Models\ModelName::where('reference', '2c101e9b-9bb8-4efe-9e12-3c94a19d658d')->get()
= Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4765
    all: [
      App\Models\ModelName {#4781
        id: 9,
        reference: "2c101e9b-9bb8-4efe-9e12-3c94a19d658d",
        user_id: 2,
        deliverer_id: 6,
        amount: "5000.00",
        amountCharged: "5000.00",
        fees_applied: "[]",
        payment_method: "{"card": "cardDetails"}",
        delivery_address: "city",
        region: null,
        lat: "xxxxxxx",
        long: "xxxxxx",
        status: "accepted",
        paymentstatus: "paid",
        delivered_at: null,
        created_at: "2023-04-01 09:56:07",
        updated_at: "2023-04-02 00:01:34",
        deleted_at: null,
      },
    ],
  }
```

However, the following should return NULL, but it returns the wrong data instead

```
App\Models\ModelName::Where('id', "2c101e9b-9bb8-4efe-9e12-3c94a19d658d")->get();
= Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4763
    all: [
      App\Models\ModelName {#4774
        id: 2,
        reference: "3f716d49-48e5-46be-bb91-33b35a042b9f",
        user_id: 5,
        deliverer_id: null,
        amount: "5000.00",
        amountCharged: "5000.00",
        fees_applied: "[]",
        payment_method: "{"wallet": "wallet"}",
        delivery_address: "city",
        region: null,
        lat: "xxxxxxxx",
        long: "xxxxxxxx",
        status: "pending",
        paymentstatus: "unpaid",
        delivered_at: null,
        created_at: "2023-03-12 13:33:20",
        updated_at: "2023-03-12 13:33:20",
        deleted_at: null,
      },
    ],
  }
```

I have tried typecasting the reference to string i.e., `(string)"2c101e9b-9bb8-4efe-9e12-3c94a19d658d"` this matches the wrong record. Even with single quotes nothing seems to work.

From my troubleshooting, it seems that the `where()` method or MySql is converting `'"2c101e9b-9bb8-4efe-9e12-3c94a19d658d"'` to `(int)2` and matching it to the record with `id: 2`

Removing the leading `2` returns `Null` as expected i.e.`'"c101e9b-9bb8-4efe-9e12-3c94a19d658d"'` === `Null`

Note that the `reference` field is plain old string type.

**Question**
What's the cause/explanation of this? I do not have access to the MySQL database here to run the query directly, so can't tell if this is a PHP, Laravel, or MySQL problem.

Comment: `id` is an integer column, so mysql ignores anything that doesn't match an integer. So it's only seeing `2`. You may want to see if it the string is an integer before trying to use it.

Comment: Thanks @aynber I thought casting it to string should force it to see the whole string. Is there anyway to make this read the whole string?

Comment: All of the comparisons in a `where` clause are in the database, so you can [cast id as string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast). It would probably be easier, faster, and saner to check the type of the value before you check the database, and decide if you want to check it against the `id` or `reference` columns.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075218/mysql-treats-string-as-integer

Comment: Thanks @Don'tPanic and aynber I am using is_string() now to check the input value before building my query. That works perfectly. Insightful day!

Answer (score 0):

The reason here is that Eloquent assumes primary key is integer. You should set on your `ModelName` the following property:

```
/**
 * The data type of the auto-incrementing ID.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

Please read [primary key](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#primary-keys) explanation for more details.